# rpm -ivh file.rpm throws error already installed

Tags: linux, rpm

I uninstalled gitlab using `gitlab ctl uninstall`, removed `/etc/gitlab, /var/opt/gitlab,/var/log/gitlab`. After that I erased rpm using `rpm -e file.rpm`. Now when I am installing a new `file.rpm`, it throws an error already installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it using `rpm -Uvh filename.rpm`. It got upgraded. There was an error while using `rpm -e filename`. Only filename should be given and not with `.rpm` extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the vestigal remains of your old gitlab installation, you can use `rpm -Uvh /path/to/the.rpm`.

Comment: But this will upgrade right? I want fresh installation.

Comment: Run `rpm -qa | grep rpmname`.  It's possible your system thinks it's still installed; possibly because your `rpm -e` failed.